# .NET Maui - Navigating back from the page requires double-tapping

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am building a .NET MAUI Android and iOS application and I implemented page in which I pick employees from the picker component, I also implemented clearing of the picker selection in OnDisappearing method.

This is the code-behind:

```
public partial class APAchievedBenefits
{
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        _adminAchievedBenefitsViewModel.AchievedBenefitsForEmployee.Clear();
    }
}
```

The issue occures when i try to navigate-back on my back button from the page. I need to do it twice when no-element is selected, but in case one element is selected then it works properly.

Comment: You can also refer to this doc: [Push pages to the navigation stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-8.0#push-pages-to-the-navigation-stack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by providing an additional if statement that will check if my current page is **not-present** in the navigation stack.

This will always be true since we're in the OnDissapearing method, and by doing that we're only clearing our elements from picker upon navigating-back from our page.

Here is the code modification:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        if (!Navigation.NavigationStack.Contains(this))
        {
            _adminAchievedBenefitsViewModel.AchievedBenefitsForEmployee.Clear();
        }
    }
```